# Php: does "static" behaves like C?

Tags: php, optimization

I have a "main class" that generates a db access. Something like:

```
class ObjetBd extends Objet
{
    protected $bd;
    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
        $this->bd = new BD();
        $this->bd->connect();
    }   
}
```

This is "clean" code to me (I've removed the comment for the sake of compactness).

Now my problem is that `$this->bd` is generated for each object.

I'm wondering whether static object are generated + initialized once.

I'd like to call `connect()` once and use only one connexion, without using direct calls to static method (i.e. keep on using `$this->bd` like before)

If it's the case, could you please say if the following code will work flawlessly, and if it should use less ressources:

```
class ObjetBd extends Objet
{
    static private $bd_static;

    protected $bd;

    public function __construct()
    {   
        parent::__construct();
        if (!isset(self::$bd_static)) {
            self::$bd_static = new BD();
            self::$bd_static->connect();
        }
        $this->bd = self::$bd_static;
    }
}
```

Comment: :paperclip: it looks like you are implementing a singleton pattern Please take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php  :D

Comment: @Nanne I've read closely your link. If you read it closely you'll see it's not a singleton pattern (even though reading *quickly* my question may lead to such ideas **`;)`**).

Comment: I'm not really sure it is different? You seem to imply in your question you want a single database object (**"generated + initialized once."** as you say). Wouldn't that _be_ a singleton? @evert: I agree that singletons might need to be avoided, but that does not mean the question is not about them? So do not ignore the singleton comment, but maybe add an answer to steer away from the problem (that's why it was a comment and not an answer in the first place).

Comment: It's generated + initialized once, but it's neither declared like the sample in your link, nor used like the sample in your link. You're right on both 2 first points, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are doing this correct.
Ignore the singleton comment, singletons are a good thing to avoid.

Although I do want to make a suggestion:

I'm going to assume BD is some kind of database. The power of OOP is the ability to subclass things, and replace objects without changing behaviour.

So it *may* be better to just pass your $bd object in the constructor. Just something to keep in mind. This is called 'dependency injection' or 'inversion of control'.

Comment: I do agree with you with singletons. I've already had problems (don't remember when and why, but my experience tells me that what you suggest is right).

Comment: By the way passing `$bd` implies that all objects which want to use an object that is a descendant of `ObjetBd` **must have** a `$bd` object to give to the constructor.

Comment: If subclasses have another means to fetch a 'BD-compatible' object, you can actually omit arguments from the `__construct` method in sub-classes.

For some reason arguments for functions are always enforced to have a similar signature, _except_ for the constructor.

Comment: Right now you couldn't write a unittest for this class, without also having to setup the BD class. The benefit of dependency injection is that you could have inserted a 'mock' BD instance.

Comment: Plus it helps with inheritance problems.. if you use self:: instead of static::

Comment: I don't get the principle of "dependency injection". Unfortunately I don't have the time to spend some time to learn this whereas I'd like very much to do so... thank you very much for your answer.